# Pesquisar string num array com jquery

Tags: jquery

Pessoal estou com um problema no codigo.

```
function escreveNoticias() {

    var table_body = $("#lista-noticias tbody");
    table_body.empty();

    for (var i = 0; i<noticias.length; i++) {
        noticia = noticias[i];
        if (categorias.indexOf(noticia.categoria)>=0) {
            if (categorias.indexOf(procura)>=0) {
                var linha = "<tr class=\"realce\"><td>" + "<span>Titulo:</span>" + noticia.titulo + "&nbsp" + "&nbsp" + "&nbsp" + "&nbsp" + "<br><br>" + "<span>Categoria:</span>" + noticia.categoria + "&nbsp" + "&nbsp" + "&nbsp" + "&nbsp" + "<br><br>" + "<span>Data:</span>" + noticia.data  +  "<br><br>" + "<span>Subtitulo</span>" + noticia.subtitulo +  "<br><br>" + "<span>Artigo:</span>" + noticia.artigo +  "<br><br>" + "</td><tr>";
                table_body.append(linha);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Bem pessoal o meu problema está no seguinte, ao executar esta parte:   `if(categorias.indexOf(noticia.categoria)>=0)` eu quero ver se a categoria da noticia existe no arrray categorias e até aqui tudo bem funciona, apresenta só as noticias com a categoria que estão selecionadas atraves de checkbox, o problema vem na linha  a seguir, ao fazer isto: `if(categorias.indexOf(procura)>=0)` o que era suposto fazer era receber uma string armazenada na variavel procura e verificar se existe alguma categoria com o nome da string porém esta parte não funciona e não sei porque... A variavel procura é preenchida aqui.

```
function procurar() {
    $("#Procurar").click(function(){
        procura = ($("#TEXTO").val());
        escreveNoticias();
    });
}
```

Eu até fiz um `alert` para ver se a string chegava ao `escreveNoticias` e chega o meu problema está mesmo no `indexOf`...

Alguem me consegue ajudar?!?!

Answer (score 1):

Vou destacar alguns problemas:

1. se você declarar uma `table` no HTML sem elementos nela, um `tbody` não será gerado automaticamente.
2. o método `escreveNoticias` deveria estar recebendo as variáveis como argumento, e não como objetos globais (isso é muito importante no médio e longo termo, para a manutenibilidade do programa)
3. a associação do evento `click` ao elemento `#Procurar` ocorre dentro de uma função, que não parece estar sendo chamada, e cujo nome (*`procurar`*) não indica que será chamada com o propósito de cadastrar eventos
4. a lógica dos `if`s é estranha, você seleciona as notícias de acordo com as check-boxes (categorias), até ai ok... mas ai depois só deixa a notícia ser listada se o usuário digitar numa caixa de texto o nome de um das categorias checadas (pra que isso?)

   Você vai ter que decidir se quer que o usuário selecione as categorias através de checkbox ou de um texto que ele digita.

Os problemas 1 ao 3 estão resolvidos no snippet abaixo. O 4, já é problema de lógica, e ai terá de pensar um pouco mais sobre o real comportamento desejado.

```js
$(function() {
  var categorias = ["Esporte", "Lazer"];
  var noticias = [
    {titulo:"O time ganhou",categoria:"Esporte",data:"",subtitulo:"",artigo:""},
    {titulo:"Resort bom bonito e barato",categoria:"Lazer",data:"",subtitulo:"",artigo:""},
    {titulo:"O outro time perdeu",categoria:"Esporte",data:"",subtitulo:"",artigo:""},
    {titulo:"Viagens à lua não são mais sonho",categoria:"Lazer",data:"",subtitulo:"",artigo:""},
    {titulo:"O filme do momento",categoria:"Cinema",data:"",subtitulo:"",artigo:""}
  ];

  function escreveNoticias(procura, categorias, noticias) {

    var table_body = $("#lista-noticias tbody");
    table_body.empty();

    for (var i = 0; i < noticias.length; i++) {
      var noticia = noticias[i];
      if (categorias.indexOf(noticia.categoria) >= 0) {
        if (categorias.indexOf(procura) >= 0) {
          var linha = "<tr class=\"realce\"><td>" +
            "<span>Titulo:</span>" + noticia.titulo + "&nbsp" + "&nbsp" + "&nbsp" + "&nbsp" + "<br><br>" +
            "<span>Categoria:</span>" + noticia.categoria + "&nbsp" + "&nbsp" + "&nbsp" + "&nbsp" + "<br><br>" +
            "<span>Data:</span>" + noticia.data + "<br><br>" +
            "<span>Subtitulo</span>" + noticia.subtitulo + "<br><br>" +
            "<span>Artigo:</span>" + noticia.artigo + "<br><br>" + "</td><tr>";
          table_body.append(linha);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  $("#Procurar").click(function() {
    var procura = ($("#TEXTO").val());
    escreveNoticias(procura, categorias, noticias);
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Suponha que estão checadas as categorias: "Esporte" e "Lazer"</p>
<input id="TEXTO" />
<button id="Procurar">Procurar</button>
<p>Lista de notícias</p>
<table id="lista-noticias">
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, já consegui resolver o meu problema!

Comment: Se puder, considere adicionar uma resposta dizendo como fez para resolver o seu problema, assim pode ajudar outros que tiverem o mesmo problema.